# Could not create foreign key in Laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a project where I am using laravel 5.8. Here I want to create a foreign key. I tried lots of time but every time I got an error message on migration time. There are three tables one is trades which is primary and students, placements these are the secondary table. I want to create a foreign key on those two secondary table trade_id as the name of the key.

This is the trades table(primary table).

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

 class CreateTradesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('trades', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('trade', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('unit', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('class_room', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('total_class_room', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('workshop', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('total_workshops', 32)->nullable();
        $table->string('remarks', 32)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('trades');
}
}
```

This is the students table(secondary table).

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateStudentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 32)->nullable();
            $table->string('father_name', 32)->nullable();
            $table->string('uid', 12)->nullable();
            $table->date('dob');
            $table->string('sex', 6)->nullable();
            $table->string('status', 16)->nullable();
            $table->integer('trade_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('trade_id')->references('id')->on('trades')->onDelete('cascade');            
            $table->string('shift', 32)->nullable();
            $table->string('session', 32)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });


    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('students');
    }
}
```

This is the placements table(secondary table).

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePlacementsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('placements', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('roll_no', 32)->nullable();
            $table->string('name', 32)->nullable();
            $table->integer('trade_id')->unsigned()->nullable();  
            $table->foreign('trade_id')->references('id')->on('trades')->onDelete('cascade');                      
            $table->year('year_of_passing');
            $table->string('organization_name', 32)->nullable();
            $table->float('salary_on_joining', 8,2);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('placements');
    }
}
```

At migration time getting error.

```
$ php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrating: 2019_05_22_132427_create_notices_table
Migrated:  2019_05_22_132427_create_notices_table
Migrating: 2019_05_22_132600_create_students_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `students` add co
nstraint `students_trade_id_foreign` foreign key (`trade_id`) references `trades` (`id`) on delete cascade)

  at C:\laragon\www\projects\UIIT-admin\uiti_admin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")
      C:\laragon\www\projects\UIIT-admin\uiti_admin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      C:\laragon\www\projects\UIIT-admin\uiti_admin\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: try to change the foreign key data type to BigInt because the reference column/primary key should be the same data type of foreign key or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the foreign key as integer type but the primery key in the trades table is bigInteger type

try this one

```
 $table->bigInteger('trade_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
 $table->foreign('trade_id')->references('id')->on('trades')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreign key column code as per this

```
//In students

Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {         
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('trade_id')->nullable();
      $table->foreign('trade_id')->references('id')->on('trades')->onDelete('cascade');                   
});



//In placements

Schema::create('placements', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('trade_id')->nullable();;
      $table->foreign('trade_id')->references('id')->on('trades')->onDelete('cascade');    
});
```